# Joining two tables in Rails but not on the primary key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to do this for the last 12 hours and I can not figure this out.

I have two tables:

data:
data_id (primary key)

data text

userid int

users:
id (primary key)

name text

email text

I want to be able to pull the data so that I can have the user information, joined by data.userid with users.id

This is a really really simple SQL query, but it seems almost impossible in Rails.. Have I missed something fundamental here?

I am getting the error message:
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'users.data_id' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.data_id = 2)

Can someone explain to me in a very simple way how to achieve this please?

Thanks

Comment: do you want the SQL or the rails way? Also are you trying to pull the users (name, email), or do you want datatext.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the Rails conversions, for example the primary key is called 'id'. There are others so you might want to check of [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).

One thing which may trip you up in this specific example is pluralization, [data/datum](http://www.jmcsweeney.co.uk/computing/m150/data_datum.php).

This should get you going:

*TABLES*

```
Datas:
  id:      integer (autoinc)
  data:    text
  user_id: integer (foreign key)

Users:
  id:      integer (autoinc)
  name:    varchar
  email:   varchar
```

By the way its best to create your tables using a migration, not manually.

*MODELS*

```
class Data < AR:Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < AR::Base
  has_many :datas
end
```

*USEAGE*

```
u = User.first
u.datas
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
@data = Data.find(params[:id])
@data.user.name
```

where you are clicking on data with id 2.